# How do I test whether running from CakePHP Console?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a CakePHP Console Shell that works fine until a `Model->afterFind()` tries to add some data to the results which includes adding links, which doesn't seem to work while being called from the Console.

Is there a way to test in the `Model->afterFind()` callback function whether it's being called from a Console Shell, so that I can skip the troublesome section that I don't need anyway?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not too sure whether there's a Cake way to do it, but you can do it via regular PHP

```
 if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && empty(getClientIP())) {
      //running via CLI
 } else {
      //running normally
 }
```

Comment: Using `php_sapi_name()` to test whether we're running via the cli would have worked, especially if wrapped in an AppModel function for re-use and optimisation. However, in the end I found that I could stop the error happening by tightening up the find that triggered the problem (dropping a particular field from the query) so that the section causing the problem was never entered due to other tests already in place.

Comment: always more than one way to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're breaking MVC best-practices if your business (model) layer is having adverse effects when run in different contexts.  Whatever you're putting into Model->afterFind() should be completely agnostic to how the application is executed.

With that understood, the model layer of CakePHP is not at all aware of the execution context.  One solution would be to deal with this by passing a flag to the model layer from the shell. ie:

At the top of app_model.php:

```
var $isShellContext = false;
```

Then, in your shell:

```
$this->Model->isShellContext = true;
```

And then in Model->afterFind():

```
if(!$this->isShellContext) {
   // add links, etc
}
```